# Trouble Dual Booting Ubuntu Alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am attempting to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

I have created an unallocated space using Windows Disk Manager. I have downloaded the latest Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Desktop and have imaged a 32GB Transpeed USB drive using Rufus and that worked properly. When I have my USB drive plugged in I reboot my Dell 5530 Precision laptop and press F12. When the option shows up, I press enter to boot from removable media. The Ubuntu screen shows and it does the file system check. At the end of the check if says

> Check finished: errors found in 3 files! You might encounter problems!

and then immediately after all I see is a black screen with a single blinking underscore cursor. I left it on this screen for 10 minutes and eventually press the power button once and then the screen appears that says

> please remove the installation medium, then press ENTER:

So I do like what it says, but then it just shuts down. I eventually need to shutdown and reboot into Windows.

Note: I had a previous Ubuntu 18 on the same unallocated space prior to this and cleared that out by deleting the partition and returning it to the unallocated space using Windows Disk Manager.

What could be the issue?

UPDATE: I used another usb stick and loaded a freshly downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.2 ISO on that (I ran diagnostics using windows to ensure it was not broken or compromised and it was all green). Used rufus to image the ISO on the new usb AND IT WORKED. The first USB stick I was using must have been corrupted despite passing Windows diagnostics.

Comment: "errors found in 3 files" means a bad "burn" and/or a corrupt ISO and/or a faulty USB stick.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ok sill try to re download the iso and try again if that fails I suppose it would be the USB stick!

Comment: @ChanganAuto on windows10 if I click into the usb -> properties -> Tools -> Check and run the analyzer that "Scans and Repairs" it ocomes back with "No errors were found"

Comment: Windows software can't tell you if the installation media is valid

Comment: It turned out that the usb I was using was corrupted and needed to use another one for it to install properly.